# Is there an command for re-acquire Direct Protocol type routes?

Tags: router, route

How can I refresh the Direct protocol type Routes?

I deleted one Direct Protocol type route from Quidway route-table.

Is there an command for re-acquire Direct Protocol type routes?

```
Destination/Mask    Proto   Pre  Cost      Flags NextHop         Interface

       10.0.0.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   10.0.0.2        GigabitEthernet
0/0/0
       10.0.0.2/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       GigabitEthernet
0/0/0
     10.0.0.255/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       GigabitEthernet
0/0/0
      127.0.0.0/8   Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       InLoopBack0
      127.0.0.1/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       InLoopBack0
127.255.255.255/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       InLoopBack0
    192.168.1.1/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       GigabitEthernet
0/0/1
  192.168.1.255/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       GigabitEthernet
0/0/1
255.255.255.255/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       InLoopBack0
```

there I deleted the 

`192.168.1.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   192.168.1.1     GigabitEthernet 0/0/1`

which is Direct link to the `GE 0/0/1`. how can I re-fetch it?

---

I use the `AR2220` router in the eNSP.

Comment: Which platform is this?

Comment: I use the AR2220 router in the eNSP.